# How to set path in app's urls.py to show localhost:8000/xxx(with django2.1.8)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-2.1

I want to show topics.html through visiting localhost:8000/topics

start a project named learning_log
start an app namede learning_logs

this is url.py in learning_logs(app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('/topics/',views.topics,name='topics')
    ]
```

and this is url.py in learning_log(project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('learning_logs.urls'))
]
```

this is views.py in learning_logs(app)

```
def topics(request):
    topics=Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context={'topics':topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)
```

I runserver and visit localhost:8000/topics
it says 404Error,current path didn't match

Comment: You have `path('/topics/', ...)`, so the URL is `localhost:8000/topics/`. Normally Django will redirect and add the slash, so there might be a problem with your `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate `localhost:8000/example/`
You can define in project label `urls.py`

```
path('example/',views.something,name='example'),
```

If your `urls.py` in app label
the you need to first include it in project label `urls.py`

```
path('',include('yourapp.urls'))
```

Then go to `yourapp` app label `urls.py` and use this

```
path('example/',views.something,name='example'),
```

Then you can navigate to `localhost:8000/example/`